# Serverless function cloudwatch logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Has anyone ever created a serverless function, that the CloudWatch logs output to ElasticSearch natively?
I wonder if there's a way to configure the `function` method in the yml to output to an already-existing ES cluster.

Or is there a way to connect the CloudWatch stream (via serverless) to a lambda function, that could then send the parsed logs to ES.

Comment: im trying to do exactly this now, i have an existing es cluster and i want to be able to see cloudwatch logs in elastic search to view. Did you find a method to do this using serverless function

Comment: @Kay I achieved this by creating an ES cluster with Serverless and exporting the ARN. That same serverless service also created the "parsing" lambda that would handle all the Cloudwatch output logs and transmit to ES.
I then went to the service that writes to Cloudwatch, in this case an ECS cluster, and created a SubscriptionFilter that writes to that lambda, that subsequently writes to ES. Hope this helps! Reach out if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating an ES cluster with Serverless and exporting the ARN. That same serverless service also created the "parsing" lambda that would handle all the Cloudwatch output logs and transmit to ES.
I then went to the service that writes to Cloudwatch, in this case an ECS cluster, and created a SubscriptionFilter that writes to that lambda, that subsequently writes to ES. Here is *part* of the serverless YML file that creates the ES cluster. And then the SubscriptionFilter in the ECS YML

```
ElasticSearchInstance:
  Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
  Properties:
    AdvancedOptions:
      rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: "true"
    CognitoOptions:
      Enabled: True
      IdentityPoolId:
        Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
      RoleArn:
        Fn::ImportValue: CognitoAccessRoleForAmazonESArn
      UserPoolId:
        Ref: CognitoUserPool
    DomainName: "name-of-my-es-cluster-${env:ENV}"
    EBSOptions:
      EBSEnabled: true
      VolumeType: gp2
      VolumeSize: 10
    ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
      InstanceType: t2.small.elasticsearch
      InstanceCount: 1
      DedicatedMasterEnabled: false
      ZoneAwarenessEnabled: false
    ElasticsearchVersion: 7.4
```

---

```
  ECSESParsingLamba:
  Type: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
  Properties:
    DestinationArn:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "parsing-lambda-name-${Environment}"
    FilterPattern: "[message]"
    LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupName
```